# Dictionary style access returning None in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I have been trying to access a database in `mongodb` and then modifying the  particular fetched data into **key-value** pair for further issue. Although, my code works fine with other collections. But, It's giving me some errors with this.

> > > 1: Here is  the snippet of my code which was giving the first error:

```
kpi = sample["kpi"]
    for proc in kpi:
        volume_used = int(float(kpi[proc]["percent"][:-1]))
        volume_free = 100 - volume_used
        volume_name = kpi[proc]["folder"]

        vol_first = [volume_name, volume_used]
        vol_second = [volume_name, volume_free]
        data_first.append(vol_first)
        data_second.append(vol_second)

    value_first.append({"key": "volume used", "values": data_first})

    value_first.append({"key": "volume free", "values": data_second})


    disk_data.append({
        "key": dev["device_name"] + "," + dev["ipaddr"],
        "values": value_first
    })
    print disk_data
```

From this, The error i got was like this:

```
File "stats_server.py", line 1547, in getD3DiskData_columnchart
"key": dev["device_name"] + "," + dev["ipaddr"],
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

Then, I modified the `device_name` which was of `float` format to `string`.

> > > 2: Modified code:

```
kpi = sample["kpi"]
    for proc in kpi:
        volume_used = int(float(kpi[proc]["percent"][:-1]))
        volume_free = 100 - volume_used
        volume_name = kpi[proc]["folder"]

        vol_first = [volume_name, volume_used]
        vol_second = [volume_name, volume_free]
        data_first.append(vol_first)
        data_second.append(vol_second)

    value_first.append({"key": "volume used", "values": data_first})

    value_first.append({"key": "volume free", "values": data_second})


    disk_data.append({
        "key": str(dev["device_name"]) + "," + dev["ipaddr"],
        "values": value_first
    })
    print disk_data
```

Then, i started getting this error.

```
 File "stats_server.py", line 1530, in getD3DiskData_columnchart
kpi = sample["kpi"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

The line `kpi = sample["kpi"]` returns the documents from the particular collection.

The query i used to fetch the data is:

```
disk_util_coll = db[kpi_meta]

    disk_docs = disk_util_coll.find_one()
    sample = disk_docs
```

**Where, kpi_meta is the collection's name.**

The document `kpi` will be containing the data i need as:

```
"kpi" : {
            "none" : {
                    "usage" : "0",
                    "folder" : "/run/shm",
                    "percent" : "0%",
                    "free" : "246M",
                    "dev" : "none"
            },
            "tmpfs" : {
                    "usage" : "256K",
                    "folder" : "/run",
                    "percent" : "1%",
                    "free" : "99M",
                    "dev" : "tmpfs"
            },
            "/dev/sda1" : {
                    "usage" : "1.2G",
                    "folder" : "/",
                    "percent" : "74%",
                    "free" : "404M",
                    "dev" : "/dev/sda1"
            },
            "udev" : {
                    "usage" : "4.0K",
                    "folder" : "/dev",
                    "percent" : "1%",
                    "free" : "238M",
                    "dev" : "udev"
            }
```

Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Let me know, if i am supposed to give something more from my side.

***Thank you***

Comment: So what is `sample["kpi"]` exactly? Do you mean that "kpi" is the name of a collection from a database called "sample"? Because you cannot access documents like that. You need to issue a query.

Comment: `Sample` is containing all the fetched data from a collection and `kpi` is one of the documents of that collection. @NeilLunn

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us the query you issue, the value of  `Sample`  and your document?

Comment: pymongo returns query results as an array of objects. You can't index that array with anything other than an integer index.

Comment: @Michael9 I have edited and added the query. Please, have a look.

Comment: what is the returned document?

Comment: @Michael9 I added that as well. There are other fields i used to fetch the data but mainly i need this `kpi` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

means that "sample" is `None`. This means your find_one query didn't return a document. That is, the query didn't match any documents in the collection. Check that find_one() returns a document before trying to access its fields.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that there was no data coming from the server side. After that, it worked fine. :)